# HansGrohe lacuna faucet low water pressure

Tags: faucet, kitchen-sink

I have a Hans Grohe Lacuna faucet.  We love it, but it's started to run slow recently.  There's a filtered water tap that uses the same cold water supply, and it's running fine.  I assume it's the faucet.  I cleaned out the aerator, but that seems to not have fixed anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lacuna (and possibly other faucets) has a backflow check valve assembly in the hose.  There is a lacuna_maintenance pdf from hansgrohe that shows how to clean it.  No tools needed, other than maybe a small brush for cleaning.  Details not in the maintenance sheet:

- the blue cap thing has an o-ring.  It's tiny; be careful to do any work over a plugged sink to not lose it down the drain.
- the two white things are backflow valves.  Mine were so sticky that the valve was stuck.  Only after cleaning did i realize they were valves.
- if you’re dirty enough that you have low pressure, rinsing with water probably won't fix you, you'd need a stiff bristle brush to actually get any detritus off.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for posting this. Please be sure to give yourself a check mark so others know it's been resolved.